# How to display a programiticaly created datatable to a dynamically created datagridView?

Tags: datagridview, datatable

i want to export a datagridview to excel with selected column.
This code just give a blank .xlsx excel file.
But i want it to fill with "routine_data_grid" datagridview values with selected column.I really stuck with this problem. How to fix this problem? any help is really appreciated.

```
try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter dp = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable d = new DataTable();
            d.Columns.Add("Days");
            d.Columns.Add("Groups");
            d.Columns.Add("Room no");                        

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in routine_data_grid.Rows)
            {
                int i = row.Index;

                DataRow dro = d.NewRow();
                dro["Days"] = routine_data_grid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dro["Groups"] = routine_data_grid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                dro["Room no"] = routine_data_grid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();

            }

            DataGridView gv = new DataGridView();


            gv.DataSource = d;


            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Routine";
            for (int i = 1; i < gv.Columns.Count+1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = gv.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < gv.Columns.Count; j++)
                {


                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = gv.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();



                }
            }
            var saveFileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialoge.FileName = "New Routine";
            saveFileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
            if (saveFileDialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
            app.Quit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found it. I just use another DataGridView for other Datatable, which i keep invisible. Thats how i solve my problem.